Why does my increment Counter apparently not work?
I am trying to create a basic increment counter using Blazor web app on .NET 8. I have asked ChatGPT, I also checked some basic calculator projects on GitHub using Blazor, they have similar code for the increment count but yet mine does not work.
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<p>Current count: @currentcount</p>

<button onclick="increamentCount">Button</button>
@code {
    public int? currentcount = 0;

    private void increamentCount()
    {
        currentcount++;
    }
}


What's your rendermode?

Does My static variables in my Blazor Server app are keeping their values, even if I refresh the page or even I close the tab and login again. Why? answer your question?

Please, for the sanity of whoever will be looking at your code in the future, change that increament to increment.

The problem is here:
<button onclick="increamentCount">Button</button>

It needs to be:
<button @onclick="increamentCount">Button</button>

Without the @ symbol your onclick is treated as standard html, and the browser looks for a javascript method increamentCount.
@onclick is a Blazor directive and will go to your C# code in search of your increamentCount method.
